# Why Python library import doesn't work via NRPE

Tags: python, linux, centos6, nrpe, centreon-api

I'm developing plugin Nrpe in Python.

When i try to execute my code it works well on my machine. But when the NRPE execute it, an error occurs : 'No Module named pycurl'

I'm working on CentOs6.10 with Python 3.4 and i've installed pycurl with easy-install, the path to pycurl.py is /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages//usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl.py

And my PYTHONPATH = ['/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

I hope somebody could help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: I've modified the PYTHONPATH doing sys.path.append() but i want to know if i can avoid this workaround and why the environment has such behaviour.

Comment: What value did you append? Your PYTHONPATH seems right. How does nrpe launch your script?

Comment: I append the full path to the pycurl.py file : sys.append('/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl-7.43.0.5-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg')

Comment: Scripted launched by Centreon

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:
python3 -m pip install pycurl

You may want to use: python3 -m pip install --user pycurl
or a virtual environment.

pycurl doesn't come with python.  You have to install it with pip from pypi.

Comment: It's useful to use python3 -m pip, instead of easy_install or calling the pip shell-callable.  If you are explicit with your interpreter, than you largely eliminate the problem of installing into one interpreter and running your script(s) with another.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i assume that easy_install uses pip ? However when i try to use pip it gives me 'RuntimeError : Python 3.5 or later is required'.

Comment: pip is a newer competitor for easy_install.  About the only time I use easy_install anymore is to install pip.  If you invoke pip with python3.4 -m pip install pycurl, that may help.